# Is crash report related to auto layout mismanagement in iOS

Tags: ios, crash, autolayout

I have a crash report in my iOS app which I am not able to understand root cause. But from stack trace I see there is something wrong happening in my auto layout which I couldn't understand. Can some one help me in finding the cause of the issue?

```
CoreFoundation 0x342c22a3 __exceptionPreprocess + 163   
libobjc.A.dylib 0x3bfa697f objc_exception_throw + 31
CoreFoundation 0x342c1d85 -[NSException name] + 1
Foundation 0x34c7319d -[NSISEngine substituteOutAllOccurencesOfBodyVar:withExpression:] + 425
Foundation 0x34c7356b -[NSISEngine pivotToMakeBodyVar:newHeadOfRowWithHead:] + 299
Foundation 0x34c7412b -[NSISEngine minimizeConstantInObjectiveRowWithHead:] + 203
Foundation 0x34c75fa3 -[NSISEngine tryUsingArtificialVariableToAddConstraintWithMarker:rowBody:usingInfeasibilityHandlingBehavior:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 243
Foundation 0x34c76de9 -[NSISEngine tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 501
Foundation 0x34c7fbbf -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 395
UIKit 0x365033c1 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 129
UIKit 0x365044a9 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _constraints_didChangeAutoresizingConstraintsArrayForContainedView:] + 197
UIKit 0x3650475f -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _invalidateAutoresizingConstraints] + 79
UIKit 0x36504575 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _constraints_subviewDidChangeSuperview:] + 133
UIKit 0x360cc8b7 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1519
UIKit 0x360e9af7 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _addContentSubview:atBack:] + 71
UIKit 0x360e993f -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _addContentSubview:atBack:] + 131
UIKit 0x360fc0a5 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleHeadersAndFootersNow:] + 1701
UIKit 0x360fa50b -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1815 
UIKit 0x361117cf -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 207
UIKit 0x360cd803 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 259
QuartzCore 0x35e77d8b -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 215
QuartzCore 0x35e77929 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 461
QuartzCore 0x35e7885d _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 17
QuartzCore 0x35e78243 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 239
QuartzCore 0x35e78051 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 317
QuartzCore 0x35e77eb1 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 61
CoreFoundation 0x342976cd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 21
CoreFoundation 0x342959c1 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 277
CoreFoundation 0x34295d17 __CFRunLoopRun + 743
CoreFoundation 0x34208ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
CoreFoundation 0x34208d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
GraphicsServices 0x37dd02eb GSEventRunModal + 75    
UIKit 0x3611e301 UIApplicationMain + 1121
MyApp 0x00061a57 0x0005f000 + 10839
libdyld.dylib 0x3c3ddb20 start + 0
```

It says

```
 NSGenericException 
*** Collection <__NSSetM: 0x1e514ee0> was mutated while being enumerated.
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue, with 10.9.3 Did you found out what it was ?

Comment: @theReverend : I didn't find the exact reason why it was happening, but I made all UI update API calls explicitly called on main thread, so this solved the problem.

Comment: Yep that was my same problem, changing subviews not on a background thread. Finding out which ones though was a totally guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this could be an error in Apple's code. NSISEngine is apparently mutating an NSSet while enumerating it, and you are not directly doing that.

Having said that, though, this could certainly be a bad side-effect of a bug in your code or xib(s) that is expressing itself in a confusing way.

Report the issue to Apple and send them a reproducible test case if possible. Create a new Xcode project, or send them a reduced copy of your current project, and explain how to make this happen.

Comment: OK thanks for the inputs, I am not sure what is wrong in layout setup, double checked everything and it appears as correct. And one more thing is this issue is difficult reproduce, Our testing has reported it and I am still finding difficult to regenerate the issue. I will post this to apple.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Make sure you're calling the `UIView` methods on the main queue.

I met this issue due to this reason.